# SQL Server - Only filter records where column equals value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have following (fictional) dataset

```
 ID  | Name | Location | LastUpdated
 1   | Bill | Germany  | 2017-01-02
 2   | Bill | Germany  | 2017-01-03
 3   | Bill | Germany  | 2017-01-04
 4   | Bill | Germany  | 2017-01-05
 5   | Jack | U.K      | 2017-01-02
 6   | Jack | U.K      | 2017-01-03
 7   | Jack | U.K      | 2017-01-04
 8   | John | Japan    | 2017-02-22
 9   | John | Japan    | 2017-02-23
 10  | John | Japan    | 2017-02-24
 11  | John | Japan    | 2017-02-25
```

With my dataset I want to remove all records where `lastupdated` equals `2017-01-03`

I also want to remove all of `John`'s records where `lastupdated` equal or is greater then `2017-02-24`

I tried following SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE (LastUpdated <> '2017-01-03')
AND (Name <> 'John' AND LastUpdated >= '2017-02-24')
```

But this way, it only returns the records with a LastUpdated greater then `2017-02-24`

It seems pretty basic, but I can't work it out. Any ideas?

Comment: The way to correctly query date in TSQL is in this format: yyyymmdd, not yyyy-mm-dd. Take a look at Larnu's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transcript your requirements like this:

> I want to remove all records where lastupdated equals 2017-01-03

This is correct from your attempt:

```
LastUpdated <> '2017-01-03'
```

> I also want to remove all of John's records where lastupdated equal or
>   is greater then 2017-02-24

This one is a little trickier. Either the record we want to display **isn't John's** *OR* the record **is John's *AND* the date has to be lower than 2017-02-24**. This is expressed like the following:

```
 (
    Name <> 'John' OR
    (Name = 'John' AND LastUpdated < '2017-02-24')
 )
```

So the final expression would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table]
WHERE 
    LastUpdated <> '2017-01-03' AND
     (
        Name <> 'John' OR
        (Name = 'John' AND LastUpdated < '2017-02-24')
     )
```

Also if `name` can hold `NULL` values, you might need another OR expression that checks for `NULL`:

```
 (
    Name <> 'John' OR
    Name IS NULL OR
    (Name = 'John' AND LastUpdated < '2017-02-24')
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as a `NOT` condition to keep it simple:

```
WHERE NOT (
    (lastupdated = 2017-01-03)
    OR
    (name = 'John' AND lastupdated >= '2017-02-24')
)
```